# PhpMyAdmin ошибка 500

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu, mysql

Господа, установленный из пакетов на ubuntu 13.04 phpMyAdmin, выдает ошибку 500 Internal Server Error на странице "Настройки", хотя все остальные работает.Пробовал

```
chown -R root:www-data /usr/share/phpmyadmin /etc/phpmyadmin /etc/mysqlchmod -R g+w /usr/share/phpmyadmin /etc/mysql /etc/phpmyadmin
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а что же пишет error.log апача?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давно не посещал ресурс, пора бы закрыть вопросы. Вопрос решился установкой PMA из архива с оффсайта.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь может быть много причин, и просмотр ваших серверных логов может дать объяснение возникновению данной ошибки.

```
# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```